# Assigning different values to multiple subarrays

Tags: r, sample, sub-array

I have an array, x, with random values from 1:10 assigned to each subarray within x.

```
x <- array(sample(1:10), dim = c(5, 5, 2)) # 5 rows, 5 columns, 2 levels
x
```

This gives

```
x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6    7    6    7    6
[2,]    8    5    8    5    8
[3,]    9   10    9   10    9
[4,]    3    4    3    4    3
[5,]    2    1    2    1    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    7    6    7    6    7
[2,]    5    8    5    8    5
[3,]   10    9   10    9   10
[4,]    4    3    4    3    4
[5,]    1    2    1    2    1
```

In each subarray above sample(...) randomly selects values in 1:10 and assigns them to x.

Is there an existing R function that randomly assigns a proportion of values to each level of an array automatically? Say, only 1:2 to the first level, only values 8:9 the second level and only values 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10 to the third level.

I know how to do this with subsetting ([]), but subsetting becomes tedious when the number of levels is large (say 10 or more, instead of only 3 (as above)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `abind` library has the function `abind` that will help in doing what you want.

I implemented a list with all of the desired ranges and then used that list to construct the new array with the third dimension. The `along` parameter tells `abind` to add in the third dimension.

```
subsets <- list(c(1,2),c(8:10),c(3,4,5,6,7))
# first array
x <- array(sample(subsets[[1]],25,replace=T),dim=c(5,5))
# 2:n arrays added to x
for (i in 2:length(subsets)) {
    x <- abind(x,array(sample(subsets[[i]],25,replace=T),dim=c(5,5)),along=3)
}
```